# deploying azure web role application for blob storage on virtual machine IIS

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I have a web role based application developed in .net MVC 4.5. We are using Microsoft Azure storage.

I have published the application through VS2013 to Microsoft Azure, and this works fine for me. I want to move application to client Azure account. I have used client's ENDPOINT setting, and Tested on my local machine, Blob storage is working fine. Document are uploading.

Now I have published this application and trying to run on client virtual machine IIS server. There I have encountered an Exception saying that `"External component Exception"` means blob storage is not connecting or Azure SDK version Issue.

I have developed using Azure SDK 2.9 and client has 2.8 SDK version.

Comment: I "think" you're using web roles (cloud services), right? You tagged it as virtual machines (but Virtual Machines are not the same thing as Web Roles). Please edit to clarify. Also: please provide more detail - right now it would just be guessing.

Comment: Yes David, I am using cloud services. I am trying to host this application on client's Virtual Machine.

Comment: Ok your clarification is still confusing: cloud services cannot be hosted in a virtual machine. It's not clear if you're really trying to deploy a web/worker role to an Azure Virtual Machine, or to a cloud service (web/worker role), in your client's subscription.

Comment: I am trying to deploy on Azure virtual machine using clients subscription.